# How to use remove.attr on data-position and then print?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to write a function that will remove the footer's data-postion fixed attribute, then print the page. I have this linked with an onclick event, but it has no effect to the page.

```
function printpage(){
    $('#footer').removeAttr('data-position');
    javascript:window.print()
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should not be a `javascript` word in there...

```
function printpage(){

    $('#footer').removeAttr('data-position');

    window.print()
}
```

I expect you were copying and pasting from the `href` of a page element, where the actual javascript code it prefixed with `javascript:` but inside executing javascript, it will produce an error.